# Javascript AngularJs (NG1) If ng-model value is null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJs (Angular1) in a project and I have an ng-model which gets a value:

```
<input id="myinput" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.myDate" ng-required="true" />
```

This works fine as far as ctrl.myDate is not null be breaks the code when it's null

Is there a way where I can check if the value is null and add (for example) today's date if it's null, so it doesn't break?

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean *breaks* ?

Comment: With Breaks, I mean that I get TypeError: Cannot Read property ... of Null

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could add more of your code.

Comment: I'm just looking into adding a condition ... eg: ng-model="IF ctrl.myDate == null ... else ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input ng-if="ctrl.myDate" id="myinput" type="text" class="form-control" ng-
   model="ctrl.myDate" ng-required="true" />
 <!-- default date when myDate is null -->
 <input ng-if="!ctrl.myDate" id="myinput" type="text" class="form-control" ng-
   model="ctrl.defaultDate" ng-required="true" />
```

You can store a defaultDate in the $scope.ctrl.

Answer (score 0):

1) Supposing that `ctrl.myDate` is null, then it is probably initialized somewhere in your controller. Based upon that, **the right place to replace the model value is your controller and not the view**.

So in this case your code might look something like this:

```
  function setDate() {
    const today = new Date();
    vm.myDate = getDate() || today; // If date is null then assign today.
  }

  function getDate() { //This might be an http call that brings the date.
    return null;
  }
```

2) On the other hand if your model is just for presentation purpose you can do something like this using `ng-value` directive, but there is probably no reason to use `input` tag.

```
<input id="myinput" type="text" class="form-control" ng-value="ctrl.myDate || ctrl.today" ng-required="true" />
```

Here's a [working sample based on your question](https://jsfiddle.net/9xy3851g/).

Answer (score 0):

Can you move the condition to where you controller is initialized rather than in the ng-model? e.g. ng-init?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var testController = this;

  testController.init = function (dateInput) {
     if (dateInput !== null) {
         testController.myDate = dateInput !== null ? dateInput : getDate();
     }
  };    
}]);
```

and

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as ctrl" ng-init="ctrl.init(yourDate)">
    <input id="myinput" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.myDate" ng-required="true" />
</div>
```